# Find nth appearance of string in a string, which is not a string but a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a function, which returns nth appearance of a string in another string and returns value as integer. If works with 3 arguments, 2 of them are declared as string and one is declared as integer (appearance number). I'm trying to understand how to handle array value (declared as variable) so it works with the code. 
Function code here:

```
Function FindN(sFindWhat As String, _
sInputString As String, N As Integer) As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Application.Volatile
FindN = 0
For J = 1 To N
FindN = InStr(FindN + 1, sInputString, sFindWhat)
If FindN = 0 Then Exit For
Next
End Function
```

Actual part of the sub:

```
'''inicjowanie szyku gdzie pierwszy wyraz to kod, drugi to link do GA, trzeci to kod do RC'''
Dim szykkoncowy As Variant
ReDim szykkoncowy(1 To 100, 1 To 3)

i = 1
For J = 1 To UBound(szyk(i))
For i = LBound(szyk) To UBound(szyk)


    If szyk(i)(J) Like "*GA*" Then
    szykkoncowy(J, 1) = FindN("/", szyk(i)(J).value, 3)
    szykkoncowy(J, 2) = szyk(i)(J)
    szykkoncowy(J, 3) = Replace(szyk(i)(J), "GA", "RC")

    Else
    End If


Next i
Next J
```

if I will replace second argument with something hard-coded like "asfasf/asfasf/asf/asfasf/" it will return what I'm after. I'm sure it has got something to do with how do I declare arguments. How do I make variable from an array to be a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA: convert Variable Array to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202578/vba-convert-variable-array-to-string)

Comment: Why `Application.Volatile`? Is that function called by a worksheet function, returning in a cell? When you use `InStr` function, you can use `Cstr(sInputString)`  and `Cstr(sFindWhat)` to be sure it is a string to be analyzed.

Comment: Hello! Stil alive?

Comment: @faneDuru. Thank you very much , Cstr was the function I needed. Topic can be closed.